# Gradient not working on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, css, safari, google-visualization

I am using Google line charts and to give a gradient effect to line chart I have used Fiddle as google charts don't have an option to apply gradient. But this gradient is not working on iOS devices. Can anyone tell me if any work around is available for this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: show exactly how you are applying this gradient - chances are you're doing something that ios browser doesn't understand

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/3h0dpxde/1/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
.your_class {
background-color:#FF8B00;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 100px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
box-shadow: inset 0px 100px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
```

Comment: As you can see I have mentioned one link in question, that shows that I am creating gradient from Javascript. So please have a look at that code please and let me know if I need to make any changes in that.
Thanks